# Upgrading to espresso 3.0.1 causes test to fail

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am trying to upgrade my espresso version from 2.2.2 to 3.0.1.  All of my tests pass in 2.2.2, but most fail when I upgrade.  I get the following error on most of my tests:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch activity
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.startActivitySync(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:443)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.launchActivity(ActivityTestRule.java:332)
at com.moneyboxapp.DelayedActivityTestRule.launchActivity(DelayedActivityTestRule.java:34)
at com.moneyboxapp.activities.SplashScreenActivityTest.incorrectResetPasswordSendsYouToFirstScreen(SplashScreenActivityTest.java:44)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:385)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=moneybox://resetpassword/userId flg=0x10008000 cmp=com.moneyboxapp.test/com.moneyboxapp.activities.SplashScreenActivity }
at android.app.Instrumentation.startActivitySync(Instrumentation.java:396)
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.access$101(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:96)
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation$4.call(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:419)
at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation$4.call(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:416)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I have defined all the activities in the manifest.  Here is the android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <!-- Mixpanel -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- End Mixpanel -->
    <application
        android:name=".MoneyboxApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Moneybox.NoActionBar">
        <receiver
            android:name="com.appsflyer.SingleInstallBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="f074a08d34ad2441e22eeace1f9ab36a9a65fb80" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.mixpanel.android.MPConfig.EnableDebugLogging"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <service
            android:name=".push.MessagingService"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".push.InstanceIdService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".services.roundups.Service"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="app" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        //list of activities
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong or what has changed in 3.0.1 compared to 2.2.2?

Thanks

Comment: can u show your `manifest.xml`

Comment: Have updated the question